# How do i fix this wrong format in jsx when typing in HTML files?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

so i just learning how to use react in my project and i keep getting error code format when saving JSX in html form.

anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Please help me, this format is killing me, thank you!

Comment: use prettier formatter or ES6 entension

Comment: fyi, i already add them to my extension, but it doesn't work

Comment: can you provide more details like, what code editor are you using or any extension?